# Why only first loop is working and rest are not?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner and know almost nothing about coding.
I am trying to print a table using all three loops in the C++ language but only the first loop is working.
plz have a look and explain the possible reason behind this.
here is my code:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, i=1, result=1;
    cout << "Enter the table you want: ";
    cin >> n;

    //using for loop
    cout<<"using for loop";
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        result=n*i;
        cout<<endl<<n<<" x "<<i<<" = "<<result;
    }


    //using while loop
    cout<<"\n\nUsing while loop";
    while (i<=10)
    {
        result= n*i;
        cout<<endl<<n<<" x "<<i<<" = "<<result;
        i++;
    }


    //using do-while loop
    cout<<"\n\nusing do-while loop";
    do
    {
        result=n*i;
        cout<<endl<<n<<" x "<<i<<" = "<<result;
    }while(i<=10);
}
```

Comment: Try printing out the value of `i` after first loop and see what it is.

Comment: you haven't reset what `i` is

Comment: When a program does anything you don't expect, print out the variables used in the decision and verify that they are correct. An excellent tool that comes with almost every compiler is the debugger. With a debugger you can execute the program at your speed and watch what the program does as it does it. Very enlightening, and probably second only to the compiler in improving programmer productivity. It takes a bit of practice, but the sooner you get a grasp on using the debugger, the sooner you can reap the massive time-savings. And by Grabthar's hammer, what a savings.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that there are some errors in your code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, i = 1, result = 1;
    cout << "Enter the table you want: ";
    cin >> n;

    //using for loop
    cout << "using for loop";
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        result = n * i;
        cout << endl << n << " x " << i << " = " << result;
    }


    //using while loop
    cout << "\n\nUsing while loop";
    i = 1; //In the original code, i was not reset to 0, therefore the loop ended instantly.
    while (i <= 10)
    {
        result = n * i;
        cout << endl << n << " x " << i << " = " << result;
        i++;
    }


    //using do-while loop
    cout << "\n\nusing do-while loop";
    i = 1; //i is reset by me again
    do
    {
        result = n * i;
        cout << endl << n << " x " << i << " = " << result;
        ++i; //You also forgot to increment i after every loop.
    } while (i <= 10); //the same thing happened here as in the while
}
```

The first loop, the `for`, worked because `i` was 1, and it incremented after every loop. The second loop, the `while`, didn't work because `i` wasn't reset, so it didn't run the loop because the ending criteria was already met. The third loop, the `do while` didn't work either because `i` wasn't reset, and like the `while`, it met the criteria for ending instantly. You also forgot to increment i after every loop in the `do while`.

To fix this, I reset `i` to 1 before the start of every loop, and added the increment to the `do while`.

Now, when you run it, you can see that it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, i=1, j=1, k=1 ,result=1;
    cout << "Enter the table you want: ";
    cin >> n;

    //using for loop
    cout<<"using for loop";
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        result=n*i;
        cout<<endl<<n<<" x "<<i<<" = "<<result;
    }


    //using while loop
    cout<<"\n\nUsing while loop";
    while (j<=10)
    {
        result= n*j;
        cout<<endl<<n<<" x "<<j<<" = "<<result;
        j++;
    }


    //using do-while loop
    cout<<"\n\nusing do-while loop";
    do
    {
        result=n*k;
        cout<<endl<<n<<" x "<<k<<" = "<<result;
        k++;
    }while(k<=10);
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon because they tend to produce [Cargo Cult Programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). It's easy to salvage this answer by adding an explanation of what the asker had wrong, what you changed, and how the change fixed the problem.